# ActiveRecord boolean value returning "f", "t"

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've added a boolean column to my active record migration

```
class AddIncludeInConsolidationToCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :companies, :include_in_consolidation, :bool, :default => true
  end
end
```

Whenever I fetch a record from the database I get "f" or "t" instead of true  or false.

Is activerecord not supposed to automatically handle the type casting to and from the database.

It's like `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quoted_true/false` are defaulting to true.

What is the best way around this? Ideally it should just work, a boolean column should return a boolean by default not a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

't' and 'f' are what PostgreSQL uses for boolean values.

'bool' is not a valid datatype for a Rails migration.  You need to use 'boolean'.  My guess is that 'bool' is getting the column created in the database, but Rails is confused when the data is loaded into a model.  Change and rerun the migration and I bet everything works out.

Comment: It's always the blindingly obvious in hindsight.

Answer (score 0):

May be I'm wrong, but the booleans are saved as 'f' or 't' in PostgreSQL.

But you can use the traditional true/false in your RoR logic. Given a User model with a boolean attribute named "active" you can do

```
 if !user.active?
   # do something
 else
   # do something else
 end
```

As you can see the true/false test works fine...

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

> While boolean values are output using t and f in postgresql, "The key words TRUE and FALSE are the preferred (SQL-compliant) usage:"

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-boolean.html

Not sure why this choice was made.

Comment: I think this choice isn't made directly by ActiveRecord, it's handled deeper down in the Ruby `pg` gem:

https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/blob/fb465855ce1dd12cf7eb69c92af222052aa956ce/ext/pg_text_encoder.c#L72-L108